# Should answers or comments be edited to not use the words "above" or "below"?

Tags: discussion

I have come across a number of answers that relate to existing answers or comments, using directional words like above or below. If a user comes to a question with existing answers, the "Your Answer" box is at the bottom of the page. Some users therefore will create their own answer, like the following:

> The answers above are talking from the philosophical point of view, but I'm going to answer from a technical point of view.

But if this new answer is very good, it may be voted up, or marked as the correct answer - putting it at the top of the list of answers. There will, therefore, be no answers above it.

So, because the order of answers on a page can change due to voting or being marked as the correct answer, should any answer that refers to other answers with directional words be edited? Should users be discouraged from using the words "above" or "below" in this context?

Comment: I would avoid editing the answer unless you can find other issues wrong with it, otherwise it clogs up the suggestion queue. Once you (and I) are over 2k rep, we can make such minimal edits :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Theoretically, I'd say "yes".

Practically, I'd say "don't go out of your way to do this".

There are too many answers with such references and you could spend a lifetime "fixing" things like this. However, if you've spotted something else wrong with the answer then by all means edit out the "above" or "below" - but don't forget to replace it with a mention (or link) to the answer they are referencing.

If you have less than 2k reputation and are still suggesting edits then definitely don't do it unless you're fixing the rest of the post. Once you've got 2k and don't have to have edits approved, there's nothing to stop you.

Comment: I'd post a comment here saying "I agree with the answer below", but I'm not from Australia.

Comment: I think you're probably right - more of a pet peeve of mine, I guess. I think it's something most people don't think about - at the very least, I rarely think about my own comments being mobile within a page.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that "directional" references to other answers is really terrible when posts can shift positions.  It gets even worse for answers that have the same score, since they are arranged randomly within each unique score.

Instead, you should use direct and specific attribution.  To expand on <strike>[the above answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302859/4320665)</strike> [ChrisF's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302859/4320665), you can link to the answer from the "share" link at the bottom left of the answer (near the edit and flag links).

In the specific example you mentioned, it would also make sense to either specifically name the posts or just remove the direction and reference "the answers [that] are talking from the philosophical point of view" instead.  And as always, try to fix everything you can with the post for the edits (and especially for the suggested edits).