# Unable to edit question containing non-Latin characters, warning about 'Body cannot contain...'

Tags: support, edits

I am attempting to edit [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33891670) to improve its formatting, however I am getting this error:

[image]

Whatever I change the first line to the error changes accordingly. It appears as if the validation checker is being a little overzealous in this instance. Is it being confused by the characters used within the code sample in the question?

For reference, here is the full text I am attempting to submit:

> The below function is checking Email validation:
>
> ```
> function checkEmailValid(email, result) {
>     if (email.val() == "") {
>         result.text("이메일을 입력하십시요.");
>         return false;
>     } else {
>         var re_mail = /^([\w\.-]+)@([a-z\d\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/;
>         if (re_mail.test(email.val())) {
>             var res = false;
>             $.ajax({
>                 type: "GET",
>                 url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/checkemail/" + email.val(),
>                 timeout: 2000,
>                 beforeSend: function () {
>                     result.text("이메일 확인 중...");
>                 },
>                 complete: function (jqXHR) {
>                     if (jqXHR.status == 202) {
>                         res = true;
>
>                     } else {
>                         result.text("이미 등록된 이메일입니다.");
>                         res = false;
>                     }
>                 },
>                 success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
>
>                 },
>                 fail: function () {
>
>                 }
>             });
>             alert("step2 : " + res); ////////Here is Step2!!!
>             alert("step3 : " + res); ///////Here is Step3!!!
>             return res;
>
>         } else {
>             result.text("이메일 형식이 올바르지 않습니다.");
>             return false;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> If the email is valid the function will return `true`, but oddly
>   enough res of step2 is `false` and res of step3 is `true`. What is
>   happening?
>
> Step 2 value:
>
> [image: step 2 value]
>
> Step 3 value:
>
> [image: step 3 value]

Comment: May be related to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302858/464709). Is the edit allowed if you use proper syntax, i.e. *The function below is performing email validation*?

Comment: Coming from someone that doesn't natively speak English, but: _"The below function"_ isn't really English.

Comment: As a native speaker I was taught that way, but [it appears it's not considered correct anymore](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/609/which-is-correct-the-below-information-or-the-information-below). Every day is a school day :) Anyway, to answer the question, no, grammar has no effect: http://i.imgur.com/okWKv7m.png

Comment: Even changing it to `My function...` gives the error as: `Body cannot contain "My functio".`

Comment: Add more context to your first phrase, ie. what are you trying to do.

Comment: I think the phrase "The Below" is not allowed there .

Comment: Ok, I'm scratching my head, how the heck we are supposed to describe our problem in the first paragraph?

Comment: related: [Unable to post Chinese characters due to validation filter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263725/165773) "This is not a bug but a spam-prevention measure..."

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Arg, this was annoying to figure out... your problem is the Hangul characters. Why the error message doesn't say so? Well, if spammers figure it out, you would have more spam that you wouldn't want...

Comment: If it was those characters causing the issue, then how was the OP able to post the question originally?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no idea, but once I remove them, the message disappear.

Comment: Actually, I'm thinking along the lines that they probably combine it with another filter that makes *us* trigger it, but not OP...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the checks were put in place after the question was asked. They don't run these types of checks retroactively, but they do trigger on edits.

Comment: Thanks Will. In which case, what is the check that my edit failed on? I can see in the question now that someone managed to successfully edit it, so it can't just be due to the Hangul characters.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan they may or may not disabled this meanwhile to fix the issue... you never know! (btw, I was able to edit it too)

Comment: This seems like a complete non-issue. Spammers aren't real users with decent rep (e.g. 1k+). If someone is a logged-in user with no indications of being a spammer, there's no reason to apply this filter.

Comment: @KubaOber I think you are barking to the wrong tree.

Comment: @Braiam _"barking to the wrong tree"_ That is a strange way of saying it. I've only ever heard "barking _up_ the wrong tree", to mean something like "mistaking which path must be followed to achieve a goal". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barking_up_the_wrong_tree Does your expression mean something different?

Comment: @Clonkex It's like that, but emphasises that you should be talking to somebody else as opposed to using a different strategy.

Answer (score 23):

I just happen to meet this issue while editing [When I rotated the simulator, there are many black blocks around UIWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34334251/when-i-rotated-the-simulator-there-are-many-black-blocks-around-uiwindow):

[image]

### Solution:

Solved by **adding an empty line at top**:

[image]

Really weird issue I meet first time. And the post indeed includes some non-English characters as @Rory mentioned.

Comment: @Cœur sorry, no idea. I just met this issue in the case I mentioned. It's funny that the issue still exists for such a long time.. lol

Comment: If you want a challenge, try to fix the spelling mistake in the title of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429783/nonenglish-charecters-are-being-converted-to-decimal

Comment: @Cœur just tried, I can't make it passed as well. The only workaround I can suggest is to let the OP to provide a screenshot instead of pasting non-english characters (If we remove that Chinese sentence, it'll be ok).