# Question cannot be edited because it contains korean characters

Tags: bug, edits, spam

I’ve tried to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758881/how-to-solve-create-task-error-in-c-sharp) to fix the formatting and some general styling issues, but I got the following error message when I attempted to do so:

> Body cannot contain "It is cond".

As explained in [this related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311004/unable-to-edit-question-warning-about-body-cannot-contain) it appears that this is actually not caused by the text that the error message says, but because of foreign characters in the question. The question I am trying to edit does contain korean characters *in code*, so that’s the cause of this problem.

Now this leaves multiple issues:

1. For some odd reason, the question was able to be posted. It’s just that I am not able to edit it now. If this is the constant behavior, that you can post a question that is actually invalid by the spam validator’s rules, but no longer can edit it, then that’s not really a good way to avoid spam.
2. Since the question is already there, I expect to be able to edit it without triggering the spam validator now. This feels especially weird since I don’t even need to modify *anything* to trigger that behavior.
3. One could think that with a certain level of trust in users (e.g. 10k rep), one would be able to skip the spam validator since it’s more likely that the user knows what they are doing.
4. **This behavior seems *very hostile* to foreign languages and users speaking those languages to me.** Yes, this is an English community, but that doesn’t mean that there cannot be situations in which posting parts with foreign characters would be totally fine. The question here is a perfect example for that. There is a problem with some code, and that code happens to contain some string in another language. Even if that text was not within the code, but somewhere else in the question that would be fine too (e.g. there are many questions with display messages in other languages and referring to them should be fine in the question). Another valid example for questions with other languages would also anything encoding-related.

So can we please do something about this? It bothers me a lot that I cannot fix that question right now without changing the text in the code.

Comment: Strange. I get the error message when I do the following: 1. Click `edit`. 2. Make some change. 3. Hit `Cancel`. 4. Tell the dialog that pops up that yes, I do want to abandon my edit. So I'm not submitting any edit but I do get the error message that you report here!

Comment: You already get the error if you start editing, give the body text field focus, and then leave the text field by giving something else the focus.

Comment: @PaulRoub I reference that within my question; but as I point out, that bug is very hostile to foreign languages which made me want to bring this up in a fresh question (since that other question does not really cover anything other than “I cannot edit the question”).

Comment: The "hostile" part (attributing malice to a bug) almost led me to downvote this question (rather than upvote, which I did). But if you want more attention, multiple scattered bugs, each with a few votes, is probably not your best bet. The root bug is the same, the error message is the same -- it's a duplicate. Upvote/comment/answer the original. If you want to open a Discussion post to talk about the hostility/etc., great, but as a Bug report? This is a duplicate.

Comment: The second answer by Kjuly in the duplicate that PaulRoub found will resolve this issue.