# Body can not contain "packag", we don't like spam

Tags: support, status-bydesign, content-blocklist

I just tried to [retag a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187953/could-not-find-the-arguments-of-the-method) and got the following error-message:

[image]

First of all, I was wondering why I couldn't save a question which a 7-rep user successfully created. I literally changed nothing but add a tag. I found the solution though, I added a linebreak at the beginning, the code-block which starts right at the beginning seems to be the problem, the linebreak will be stripped on save though.

Seems like a bug in your spam-detection, therefore the question on Meta.

Edit: @gnat is totally right, I should've improved the question some more, and I just did, but no, this doesn't fix the spam-detection:

[image: Image2]

Again, a single linebreak at the beginning fixed it.

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15965/please-fix-spam-detection.

Comment: I bet there would be no warning if you did the right thing and moved the text from the bottom of the question to its top so that it would sit above code. Or, if you are lazy, simply copied question title into first line of the text so that it, again, appears above code. Even if this a bug in quality filter, I love it - because I hate it when question opens with code dump

Comment: @gnat Pretty sure the Chinese characters are triggering the spam detection here.

Comment: @edwinksl sure, that's a [known thing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311004/839601). However it seems to trigger only when combined with other issues. And if starting question with code dump is one of such issues then I like that, even if they tell me 1000 times that it's a bug

Comment: @gnat see my edit

Comment: two line breaks prior to sentence "I really don't know..." would probably do the trick too (and also make  text look better). Spam detector seems to account for heuristics that awful lot of spam dumps are submitted without line breaks in text

Comment: Clearly, the reason is that you are a spammer and the 7-rep user isn't /s

Comment: The 7-rep user must have had eggs and beans.

Comment: I was the one posted the linked question on meta.askubuntu.com . Indeed , it was possible to circumvent the errors for me as well, by deleting the referenced word in the errror and immediately saving or altering the order of words. At that time I didn't think much of it, and was more frustrated that my answer cannot be edited. But now I see  that this is indeed a bug in the spam detection. +1'ed

Comment: The user is no longer a 7-rep user.

Comment: @BhumitMehta the meta effect is real.  :-/

Comment: Looks like some overzealous (possibly automated?) blacklisting there.

Comment: I've got a similar issue today. https://www.evernote.com/l/AOy8UrYpG1dMh75l1gQr5HqVmOudfoMXLWc

Comment: @m0sa Why did you retag this as support, without answering the question? How is this not a bug?

Comment: @Stijn because the blacklist is managed by our community team, this one in particular is working as expected, see Shog's answer here http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15967/52999

Comment: @m0sa I didn't know that :) So the blacklist was modified between 04:17 and 04:29, allowing the question to be posted initially, but not allowing a retag?

Comment: @Stijn blacklist settings are per site, so the times and dates could differ on SO