# Questions containing "github" can be asked, cannot be edited

Tags: discussion, questions

I was making my way through the Help and Improvement queue when I stumbled upon a question that I thought could use some polishing, so I hit the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button and tried to make some improvements. Made the edits, clicked the <kbd>Save Edits</kbd> button, just to be informed that

[image: github in question]

OK, I understand and (let's say) I agree this. However why was question allowed to be posted in the first place? Why are not the same heuristics applied when submitting as when editing a question?

Also, why are links to github allowed (earlier I edited a question containing a link to a github repo)?

Comment: Link to the review.

Comment: @davidism I don't think adding the link would add more value to the question, let me know if you think otherwise. Also don't want to link the question here, the meta effect might do some damage to the asker.

Comment: I already did think otherwise, that's why I asked for it. At least copy the exact markup that caused the error.

Comment: @davidism the question started with `1. *github for windows*`, this  is the part that triggered the error. Also note that the question has zero votes, just tried to edit an upvoted question containing the same phrase and I was able to edit it.

Comment: @Cristik What about upvoting, editing and then retracting your upvote?

Comment: @dorukayhan hmm... tried that, got the same error. The other question had a score of 15, so maybe the heuristic is based on the question score also

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333328/body-can-not-contain-packag-we-dont-like-spam and http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15965/please-fix-spam-detection