# Spam blocker prevents update of an answer from 2009

Tags: support, spam

I was trying to update an [answer to a question about processing Japanese content from May 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/a/817506/6002174). The updates include formatting changes, some grammar and punctuation changes, replacing a link that no longer worked, and the addition links for two tools that had no links.

However, the author of the answer starts off with a few recommendations based on his experience with bilingual Japanese/English websites, and this prevented my from submitting my update; an error message said that the beginning of the answer (which I had not changed) looks like spam. I then tried alternative formulations, which were also blocked as spam, e.g. :

- I work in ...,
- I have experience ...
- My job involves ...
- This answer is based on my experience ...
- (Based on my experience ...)

These were all blocked.

Since the first comment doubted that this was the spam blocker, here is a partial screenshot: 
[image]

Then I tried to leave out the first sentence and start with a different introduction to the list of recommendations:

- A couple of recommended practices ...
- A few recommendations ...
- Recommendations: ...
- First of all ...
- When processing Japanese content ...

These were also blocked as potential spam.

In the end I did not find a formulation that passed the spam filter and had to leave the answer as it was. Can anyone give my advice on how to update that answer?

Comment: You are 100% sure those things ticked off the spam filter, as opposed to something else in the post? Did it say so explicitly?

Comment: It's likely the foreign characters. There's been a filter in for those recently, and other meta posts about posts with these characters being unable to be edited.

Comment: @Pekka웃 For each of the phrases I listed there was a popup that quoted the beginning of the phrase and added, "This looks like spam." Does this allow a different conclusion?

Comment: Check out [this previous Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311004/unable-to-edit-question-containing-non-latin-characters-warning-about-body-can) for confirmation about what I'm talking about. Sounds like the exact same issue. The team either hasn't disabled the block, or has re-enabled it.

Comment: In b4 people close this as a duplicate of that one *eyeroll*

Comment: The empty line at the top does the trick: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312812/578411

Comment: The question doesn't really belong on the site in the first place...

Comment: @rene Thanks. The empty line at the top helped.

Comment: FYI, hen the system detects that something is spam, it says that the first few words of the posts are spammy in order to trick spammers.

Comment: "I live in Japan and my job involves building and maintaining several Japanese/English bilingual websites which focus on natural language processing." Noise. Delete.

Comment: Tricking spammers is nice, but giving an actively inaccurate error message for real people is not a good user experience.

Comment: "Cheers", "edited to add some more info." Noise as well. Delete as well.

Answer (score -1):

"it says that the first few words of the posts are spammy in order to trick spammers" - How can this ever be considered a good idea, at least when dealing with a logged-in users with some rep (e.g. 1k+)?

Comment: If you block a spammer's post and tell the spammer the exact cause of the blocking then the spammer will just modify his/her post to not include the cause of the blocking. In other words, telling spammers why their crap doesn't get posted makes them work around the blocks.

Comment: @dorukayhan Users with significant reputation are never spammers, perhaps with rare exceptions of pwned accounts. I sure hope that there are records of how each time the spam filter activated, on what content, and for what user. And I'm pretty damn sure that if you looked at those records, you'd see that all activations for users with 1k+ rep who accumulated 90%+ of that rep from original questions and answers (and not score gaming by minor edits etc.)  are in error or the user's account is pwned and should be deactivated until the pwnage is resolved. With data for it don't take me on my word.