# Body cannot contain ""

Tags: discussion, support

[image]

Why there is this strange tip, I tried to delete something. but this just is a xml data.

---

My post is bellow:

From wikipedia [RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) introduce:

> RSS is XML-formatted plain text. The RSS format itself is relatively easy to read both by automated processes and by humans alike. An example feed could have contents such as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
 <title>RSS Title</title>
 <description>This is an example of an RSS feed</description>
 <link>http://www.example.com/main.html</link>
 <lastBuildDate>Mon, 06 Sep 2010 00:01:00 +0000 </lastBuildDate>
 <pubDate>Sun, 06 Sep 2009 16:20:00 +0000</pubDate>
 <ttl>1800</ttl>
 <item>
  <title>Example entry</title>
  <description>Here is some text containing an interesting description.</description>
  <link>http://www.example.com/blog/post/1</link>
  <guid isPermaLink="false">7bd204c6-1655-4c27-aeee-53f933c5395f</guid>
  <pubDate>Sun, 06 Sep 2009 16:20:00 +0000</pubDate>
 </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I tested two RSS source:

curl -o feed.xml https://www.zhihu.com/rss and
curl -o feed2.xml http://www.toodaylab.com/feed

to get the RSS data.

I find in `feed.xml` the format is not arrange in order, I means such it do not line feed, its data like bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><channel><title>知乎每日精选</title><link>http://www.zhihu.com</link><description>中文互联网最大的知识平台，帮助人们便捷地分享彼此的知识、经验和见解。</description><atom:link href="http://www.zhihu.com/rss" rel="self"></atom:link><language>zh-cn</language><copyright>© 2018 知乎(http://www.zhihu.com)</copyright><lastBuildDate>Sun, 14 Jan 2018 18:30:15 +0800</lastBuildDate><ttl>180</ttl><item><title>
```

But the `feed2.xml` data is arrange in order:

```
<?xml version="x" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="x"
        xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
        xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
        xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
        xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
        xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
        >
    <channel>
        <title>理想生活实验室</title>
        <atom:link href="http://www.toodaylab.com/feed" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
        <link>http://www.toodaylab.com</link>
        <description><![CDATA[关注创意设计与生活消费]]></description>
        <lastBuildDate>Sun, 14 Jan 2018 10:38:43 +0000</lastBuildDate>
        <language>zh-CN</language>
        <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
        <sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>
        <xhtml:meta xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" name="robots" content="noindex"/>
```

Why there is this difference between them?

Comment: It's probably caused by the Chinese characters in your feed: see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343700/4751173

Comment: Irritatingly, it's not even possible to post with a legal body and then immediately edit the "spam" content in as a workaround (I just tried).

Comment: There are lots of English errors in your proposed post; I don't know how the spam filter works, but it's possible that the errors are contributing towards the post being detected as spam. You could try fixing them (e.g. it should be "data is arranged' instead of "data is arrange" and "Why is there" instead of "Why there is") and see if you manage to post.

Comment: I delete all the Chinese characters, now it works.