# Bug when answering a question on Stack Overflow ("" detected as spam)

Tags: bug, answers

I was answering [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51333489/chinese-encoding-in-python), but then this came up:

```
Body cannot contain "".

This appears to be spam. If you feel you've received this message in error, please visit meta.
```

The thing was, my answer didn't have any double-quotes! Check it yourself, because here is the answer:

---

The output you are receiving is called a bytes object. In order to decode it, you need to do `output.decode('utf-8')`.

For example:

```
output = b'\xe8\xbf\x99\xe7\xa7\x8d\xe6\x83\x85\xe5\x86\xb5\xe6\x98\xaf\xe6\xb2\xb9\xe6\xb3\xb5\xe6\x95\x85\xe9\x9a\x9c\xe7\x81\xaf\xef\xbc\x8c\xe6\xa3\x80\xe6\x9f\xa5\xe4\xb8\x80\xe4\xb8\x8b\xe6\xb2\xb9\xe6\xb3\xb5\xe6\x8f\x92\xe5\xa4\xb4\xe6\x98\xaf\xe5\x90\xa6\xe6\x8e\xa5\xe8\x99\x9a\xef\xbc\x8c\xe7\x84\xb6\xe5\x90\x8e\xe6\x9f\xa5\xe4\xb8\x80\xe4\xb8\x8b\xe6\xb2\xb9\xe6\xb3\xb5\xe5\x86\x85\xe7\xae\xa1\xe9\x81\x93\xe5\x8e\x8b\xe5\x8a\x9b\xe6\x98\xaf\xe5\x90\xa6\xe7\xac\xa6\xe5\x90\x88\xe6\xad\xa3\xe5\xb8\xb8\xe5\x80\xbc\xe3\x80\x82'
unicode_output = output.decode('utf-8')
print(unicode_output)
```

would then output
`这种情况是油泵故障灯，检查一下油泵插头是否接虚，然后查一下油泵内管道压力是否符合正常值。`.

Another way to do this in one-line would be:
`print(b'\xe8\xbf\x99\xe7\xa7\x8d\xe6\x83\x85\xe5\x86\xb5\xe6\x98\xaf\xe6\xb2\xb9\xe6\xb3\xb5\xe6\x95\x85\xe9\x9a\x9c\xe7\x81\xaf\xef\xbc\x8c\xe6\xa3\x80\xe6\x9f\xa5\xe4\xb8\x80\xe4\xb8\x8b\xe6\xb2\xb9\xe6\xb3\xb5\xe6\x8f\x92\xe5\xa4\xb4\xe6\x98\xaf\xe5\x90\xa6\xe6\x8e\xa5\xe8\x99\x9a\xef\xbc\x8c\xe7\x84\xb6\xe5\x90\x8e\xe6\x9f\xa5\xe4\xb8\x80\xe4\xb8\x8b\xe6\xb2\xb9\xe6\xb3\xb5\xe5\x86\x85\xe7\xae\xa1\xe9\x81\x93\xe5\x8e\x8b\xe5\x8a\x9b\xe6\x98\xaf\xe5\x90\xa6\xe7\xac\xa6\xe5\x90\x88\xe6\xad\xa3\xe5\xb8\xb8\xe5\x80\xbc\xe3\x80\x82'.decode('utf-8'))`.

However, if that doesn't work, then it is probably because of the fact that your output isn't a bytes object, but is contained within a string. If that does not work, then there is another solution.

```
output = '\xe8\xbf\x99\xe7\xa7\x8d\xe6\x83\x85\xe5\x86\xb5\xe6\x98\xaf\xe6\xb2\xb9\xe6\xb3\xb5\xe6\x95\x85\xe9\x9a\x9c\xe7\x81\xaf\xef\xbc\x8c\xe6\xa3\x80\xe6\x9f\xa5\xe4\xb8\x80\xe4\xb8\x8b\xe6\xb2\xb9\xe6\xb3\xb5\xe6\x8f\x92\xe5\xa4\xb4\xe6\x98\xaf\xe5\x90\xa6\xe6\x8e\xa5\xe8\x99\x9a\xef\xbc\x8c\xe7\x84\xb6\xe5\x90\x8e\xe6\x9f\xa5\xe4\xb8\x80\xe4\xb8\x8b\xe6\xb2\xb9\xe6\xb3\xb5\xe5\x86\x85\xe7\xae\xa1\xe9\x81\x93\xe5\x8e\x8b\xe5\x8a\x9b\xe6\x98\xaf\xe5\x90\xa6\xe7\xac\xa6\xe5\x90\x88\xe6\xad\xa3\xe5\xb8\xb8\xe5\x80\xbc\xe3\x80\x82'
exec('print(b\''+ output + '\'.decode(\'utf-8\'))')
```

That should be able to fix it. Hope you got something useful out of this. Have a good day!

---

What is the problem with my answer? Please leave an answer because help is needed right now.

Comment: See the duplicate target or any linked question in that post, or [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361934/4642212) or [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263724/289905). The double quotes aren’t the characters the error message is trying to point out; these quotes will always be there. It doesn’t matter which characters the error message shows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the CJK spam blocker; if you can reduce the length of your sample output - say, 20 characters - this should go through.