# How can I help users who say their effort to provide a reproducible example was rejected by the spam filter, possibly because of Chinese characters?

Tags: support

I asked a user to provide a minimal example of their data [for their question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72142631/5784757) and they replied saying that it was rejected as spam - perhaps because it contained Chinese characters. This is unfortunate as R is used a lot for natural language processing for non-Latin alphabets.

They initially shared the data in a slightly awkward format and said the spam filter rejected it when they tried to upload it in a more reproducible `dput()` format.

Is there anything I as a normal user could do to help them provide an example that doesn't get rejected by the spam filter?

Update:

I tried to edit the example from the comments into the text and this error appeared:

> [image]

Comment: Did the question _require_ the specific text? Otherwise, ask them to use different text, like Lorum Ipsum.

Comment: I see they managed to add some text anyway?

Comment: @MartijnPieters given the question is about text parsing, I feel like the error *may* be related to the fact the characters are Chinese - changing to English might change the error.

Comment: Maybe they didn't put the code/characters in a code fence like they are now when they initially tried.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, but in a format not very useful for reproducing the data - that's why I asked them for a ``dput()`` which is easier to paste into my terminal to reproduce the data.

Comment: Perhaps this is another reason for posting images? There are too many obstacles for text, including formatting(?). Perhaps the system should be a little more helpful in various ways?

Comment: Possibly [related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371047/2821954): "*This is the CJK spam blocker; if you can reduce the length of your sample output - say, 20 characters - this should go through.*".