# Should we implement repeated characters validation in question title?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, asking-questions, quality-filter

When I read recently asked questions from top questions page, I stumbled upon a question which has repeated dash (`-`) symbols in its title. Here is the question link:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619734](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52619734)

Assumed that OP doesn't know how to write proper title, together with concerns of attempts to vandalize legitimate posts by using patterns similar to this one, can we implement question title validation which limits repeated characters to certain extent when submitting a question or (suggested) edit?

The proposed title validation system checks when a user trying to submit a question or edit with excessive repeated characters in title, then display a message in a popup e.g. `Title cannot contain excessive repeated characters`. The popup message placement can be presented in a similar way to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361934/body-cannot-contain).

Here is an image to illustrate my request, currently just show a warning with yellow border around the title input box:

[image: Title validation]

**Edit:**

Below are some vandalism attempts/incidents that I'm concerned with (intentionally select posts which is still visible to everyone and not require 10K privilege):

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52171188/2

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49595848/3

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49215463/4

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48566873/3

Comment: New title: _erfiuqhfwqijhbfrihbfwipuhgvpoiuhqefihybqwe_

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth, Compute the Scrable score and divide it by space number.

Comment: If anything, this shouldn't be a *warning* (so they can circumvent it), but rather raise an auto-flag, or silently send the post or edit to review before showing it (even if the author made the edit).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth You raise a good point about titles not containing spaces. Either they're intentionally bad, or accidentally bad.

Comment: @DragandDrop That seems like a great idea to me

Comment: In the edited examples above what was the editor attempting to accomplish by replacing so much existing text, given in most of the cases they seem to have been the originator of the question itself?

Comment: Remember [how people worked around the *problem* filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112944/350567)?

Answer (score 11):

#### No matter how you wrote such a filter, it could be easily be circumvented. Gibberish is as likely as keeping a single key pressed, and a user who is determined to post a useless title will do so no matter what. No one is posting a string of dashes *by accident*.

Also, we may end up blocking valid titles, and we all know how bothersome these automatic filters are when they malfunction.

E.g.: searching for `SELECT count(*) FROM Posts WHERE Title LIKE '%###%' AND Score > 0` returns 125 results, which are not a whole lot, but this is only one pattern I came up with, and only taking positively scored posts into account.

We could further refine it so it requires a greater repetition to actually block the title, or that it only blocks certain characters... *but in the end we would be spending effort for something that no matter what would be still **very** easily circumvented*, and could still have potential if slim negative side-effects.

At most, I'd show a popup warning the user telling them that "titles like this are often ill received", if anything, but not actually preventing the post being posted.

Comment: I know that the question filter cannot completely block gibberish question titles (especially with random character order), but at least may prevent such attempt of vandalism by intentionally holding a key and submit it as title edit.

Comment: _"we may end up blocking valid titles"_ I can't think of any examples... Can you?

Comment: @Cerbrus I think this is one of these situations where the _absence of evidence is not evidence of absence_ line applies. Nevertheless, I've provided a query that shows examples of positively scored questions with three or more repeated '#' chars. Prett sure other cases with dashes could exist. There are probably not many, I concede that, but I guess there aren't many cases of users posting "--------------" as a tiltle either.

Comment: @Cerbrus And since this is a FR, the onus should be on the proposal providing evidence (beyond that lone example) of its usefulness, and no other way around.

Comment: You claim this wouldn't work because the validation would block valid titles... The specific rules of the validation aren't even clear yet. For example, if the lower limit is set to a repetition of 8-10 times, I doubt there's a single false positive.  My point is that it's _very_ easy to dismiss a FR with _"this may break existing <X>"_, without showing at least one example that would break.

Comment: @Cerbrus Since the OP didn't specify how the rule would work, I had to assume. With a more complete FR I wouldn't have done so, of course. And yes, you can make the regex very restrictive. It will be practically useless, catching only one case in a million still trivially circumvented. Hence my reasoning on the FR not being useful enough.

Comment: Then suggest that the OP fleshes out their FR, instead of dismissing it based on a sub-optimal assumption.

Comment: @Cerbrus I still think it is a suboptimal FR, no matter how you flesh it out (although fleshing it out would be good, the FR should be defended, not the status quo). But you are ignoring part of my argument: you can make the regex more restrictive, but then you wont catch almost any fish, and could potentially block someone who can't circunvent, because they have a valid use case.

Comment: A filter like this should be pretty easy to implement. Even if it only catches a few fish a day, I'd consider it time well spent, considering the time users would have to waste fixing the titles. The FR even suggests that it may be enough only to show a warning, negating the _"block valid use cases"_ concern.

Comment: "_Title **cannot**_" doesn't read as a warning to me. But if it were a warning I'd be fine with it (as I said in my answer). If it were a  block, I would disagree, for the reasons I exposed above.

Comment: @Cerbrus I can always create an esoteric language where `--------------` is a legit language feature.

Comment: @totymedli Just use esoteric language chat rooms instead. They are likely to get 0 vote/0 answer/little view anyway.