# Why is my improve edit review refused as Spam?

Tags: support, edits, spam

In attempting to review [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15065986), I tried to do an *Improve edit* and include the images.  In so doing, the edit was refused because it *Looked like Spam*.  What was I doing wrong?

Comment: Contains the Korean looking characters which is causing this. It's been discussed before on meta here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311004/unable-to-edit-question-containing-non-latin-characters-warning-about-body-can

Comment: @BhargavRao, so that links explains why, but it does not help with what I should do in this case.  Should I just ignore it?

Comment: Aah, @Stephen, so you did not read that linked post completely. ;) .... Add a new line on top, that'll help you overcome the filter. (Funnily, spammers know this trick, but the proper users don't)

Comment: I read the *add a line*, but read quickly and thought it a random side effect, not consistent behavior.